# How to solve $\frac{1}{n}\left[1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}}\right]$

Tags: summation

I want to find an analytical expression for:

$\frac{1}{n}\left[1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}}\right]$

I know that the result is independent of $n$ when $n$ is large, because I have used MATLAB for many different values of $n$, and the answer always comes out as 4/3, but I am thus far unable to rearrange or re-express this summation to be able to show this analytically.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.  This is not for any kind of assessed work.

Comment: You may have something wrong in your calculations,since the answer is not that. Your expression is an increasing function of $n$, starting at $1$ with an asymptotic value at $4/3$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry, you are quite correct - 4/3, not 3/4 - I have updated. How did you determine this?

Comment: Just computing a few terms. Meanwhile, you have received good answers.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{n}\left[1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}}\right]=\frac{1}{n}+2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{n-k}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{n}+2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt\frac{n-k}{n}$$=
$$\frac{1}{n}+2\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{1-\frac{k}{n}}$$. When $ n \to \infty$, this turns out to be $$2\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{1-x} \right)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

You can rewrite $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-k}}}$ as
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{1-\frac{k}{n}} $$
and then use Riemann sum for an appropriate function.

Answer (score 1):

The first term $1/n\to 0$, and the rest is a Riemann sum for the integral $2\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x} \, dx = 4/3$, so that's what it converges to as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: You're welcome! But there's no need to say thanks to everybody. Just upvote the answers instead.

Comment: I tried that, but my reputation is not yet high enough to upvote (needs to be 15)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot about that. Well, only 4 to go now! :-)